# Creating a master page template in XSL for rendering using Apache FOP

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop, xslt-1.0

I need all my rendered pages conform to a specific template.

So I want to create a master page template in XSL. Initially i thought i shall make use of

flow-maps but however flowmaps are not supported by FOP (XSL 1.0). Kindly suggest an

alternative to create a master page template for my output files.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

what about implementing a preprocessing of the fo-files? 
So you have your master-template stored in a file. And then you have your fo-files with your custom page-masters containg a placeholder like $insertmasterhere$.

The preprocessing will insert the master-template in all custom page-masters. You could do it with java and String replace functions.

1. yourfofile --preprocessing--> yourfofile2 --fop--> pdf

Greetings
Johannes Perlet

Comment: can u elaborate a little bit on this ...sounds interesting !!